# How can I get good quality text print in JavaFx

Tags: graphics, javafx-8

Using Java JDK 1.8.0_45 on Windows 8.1, I’m attempting to obtain good quality text printing using JavaFx 8, but cannot get a print quality equal to that obtained using the free Adobe reader with a PDF file. The Adobe quality appears identical to that from a test print from ControlPanel>Devices and Printers>Epson Nx230>Print Test Page, both of which are good quality.

The print quality using a JavaFx Canvas is reasonable quality but fuzzy. It is certainly not a suitable standard for corporate reports.

The code I am using to create the JavaFx printout is basically as follows although I have tried a number of variations which have not improved the quality :

```
       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pageWidth, pageHeight); 
       GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

       gc.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));

       gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
       gc.fillText(pHed + pageNr, 20, 20);  // Page Heading

       PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
       printerJob.printPage(canvas);
```

The default printer is the same as used by the Adobe Reader. The resulting print-quality from JavaFx is fuzzy. Comparable print-quality produced by the Adobe PDF Reader is far superior and the test print using the Epson driver is of equal good quality to Adobe. Using other fonts including the default font appear to make little difference.

Is there a way to achieve better quality printing in JavaFx?

Comment: What happens if you just create a `Text` object and print it, instead of rendering text to a canvas and printing the canvas?

Comment: @James_D The print quality of Text appears comparable to PDF and also the Test Print ie. good. I'll have to do some tests to see if I can fully emulate a Canvas for Print Preview etc. I'm unsure what impact this would have on resources used compared to using a Canvas which I thought would do the job.

Comment: If you really need a Canvas, try adding `0.5` to each of the coordinates for the text, I.e. `gc.fillText(pHed + pageNr, 20.5, 20.5)`

Comment: I think that the Text object solves all of the problems and some. I did retry the canvas, however I think the results were about the same as previously (fuzzy). As far as I can tell at this stage, the `Text` solution appears far superior subject to further testing. Both printing and print-preview appear to be very superior using `Text`. Perhaps you could post that as an answer. At this stage I'm quite happy to abandon the `Canvas` partly because there may be another problem which I could detail separately.